# Mac app to comunicate to web app in safari

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, safari

Can someone point me in the correct direction for developing a Mac app that can communicate with a Safari site? I don't want to use web views, I want it to communicate with the website in safari itself.

I have the site sending messages to the native app just fine using the app url scheme (app name://some/url/).

Ideally I would like our app to provide single sign on for our little internal site and trigger in page JS events for reloading data etc.

I havne't been able to find any documentation on this.

Comment: `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:` -- goes to the default browser.  Is that sufficient or were you looking for more than just opening a URL?

Comment: @stevesliva I need more than opening a URL. If the user already has a page open, I want to send that specific page data. Know of a way to inject cookies into safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I ended up doing, it's quite convoluted so if anyone has a better suggestion please let me know.

My Mac App does 2 things when it starts

- Creates the the directory ~/.appwebserverfiles
- Starts a simple python webserver with the above directory as it's root

The Mac app can then write token.jsonp to this directory, like this one:

```
singleSignOnCallback({"token":"sometokenthinghere"});
```

The website using jquery will make an ajax call like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8585/token.jsonp",
    dataType: 'jsonp'
});
```

When this ajax is complete, since its a dataType of jsonp it will excecute any JS it finds in it. This will call a function called: singleSignOnCallback()

I can now inject ANY js into our internal webapp using this.

EDIT:
I should also add that this works with ANY browser.